# curl command в php скрипт

Tags: php, linux, curl

Подскажите пожалуйста

```
curl -F “data=@path/to/local/file” https://site.com
```

Что делает данная команда? 
пытаюсь переписать ее в php скрипт, в начале я подумал что тут происходит отправка данных полученных из файла, и передается в переменной data:
Получился такой скрипт:

```
function curlS($a,$b,$e) {
        $c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $a);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        if($e == "header") {
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        } else {
            if(!empty($e)) curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $e);
        }
        if(!empty($b)) {
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $b);
        }
        $d = curl_exec($c);
        curl_close($c);
        return $d;
    }
$data = file_get_contents("path/to/local/file");
echo curlS("https://site.com", "data=". $data, "header");
```

Но по ошибке от сервера получателя я понимаю, что я где то попал в просак или не так понял

Comment: Т.е Вы не понимаете, что делает команда, но пытаетесь перевести её в PHP, так?

Comment: @IgorR. Мне кажется что она означает то о чем я подумал, но есть ощущение, что я не прав. По этому и спрашиваю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам я не использовал флаг -F  но в инструкции сказано это один из примеров почитайте что бы понять смысл

Эмулируйте заполненную форму с помощью -F. Допустим, вы заполняете три поля в форме. Одно поле - это имя файла, которое нужно опубликовать, одно поле - ваше имя, а одно поле - описание файла. Мы хотим опубликовать файл, который мы написали с именем "cooltext.txt". Чтобы позволить curl размещать эти данные вместо вашего любимого браузера, вы должны прочитать исходный HTML-код страницы формы и найти имена полей ввода. В нашем примере имена полей ввода - это «file», «yourname» и «filedescription».

```
curl -F "file=@cooltext.txt" -F "yourname=Daniel"
  -F "filedescription=Cool text file with cool text inside"
  http://www.post.com/postit.cgi
```

Читайте внимательно https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html